# how to detect changes on website? python web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I started doing a monitor python for a shoe website. Now I would like to know if there is a way to know when the site is updated. For example: if there is a change in the available shoe sizes -> Send webhook to my discord

I don't know how to detect changes on the site.. please help me. If you have an idea, let me to know :)

[img webhook discord](https://pasteboard.co/JJmMbd6.png)

```py
from dhooks import Webhook, Embed
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

url = "https://en.aw-lab.com/women/shoes/new-arrivals-AW_10008AAQB.html?cgid=women_shoes_newin&dwvar_AW__10008AAQB_color=5011614"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
res.raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
img_shoes = "https://en.aw-lab.com/dw/image/v2/BCLG_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-awlab-master-catalog/default/dwd9415a8e/images/large/5011614_0.jpg?sw=843"
size = soup.select(".b-size-selector__item-0")
array_size = []

url_shoes = "[ADIDAS SUPERSTAR BOLD](" + url + ")"

embed = Embed(
    description=url_shoes,
    color=0x5CDBF0,
    timestamp='now'
)

for sizes in size:
    get_sizes = sizes.getText()
    array_size.append(get_sizes.strip())


embed.add_field(name="Size", value=('\n'.join(map(str, array_size))))

embed.set_thumbnail(img_shoes)

hook.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: if you are monitoring you should save the data you collected somewhere preferably a db. You could create a table called shoes (or whatever) and add some columns like id, name, brand, link to website, shop etc. you would create another table and add a ForeignKey to the shoes with prices and a timestamp. each time your script runs it adds another record and if the price is smaller then the last time you send some signal. For auto running the script every 5 min you could use cron.

Comment: You should probably not share your webhook api-details. Those are sensitive...

Comment: Thank you jlaur i have removed my api-details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hashlib module to compute a checksum of the page, save it and then compute it again to check if it changed. NOTE: any subtle change will change the checksum!

```
import hashlib

# ...

checksum = hashlib.sha256(res.text.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

# save it to a txt file as a comparison for the next accesses
```

Comment: i will try with haslib. it is possible to delemit an aera on the page ? for detect only changes in the aera

Comment: Use bs4 or soupsieve to access a subnode and hash that